# How to override avro namespace and name to deserialize to a specific class in KafkaAvroDeserializer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, deserialization, avro

I am trying to deserialize records in Kafka that are serialized using Avro. Unfortunately, the producer (who is not me, and has been producing for other consumers for a long time) has set a schema with a name "record". When I use avro-tool to generate a class from this schema, I get a class named 'record$', presumably because avro tool is trying to avoid a clash with the java keyword record(?).

The KafkaAvroDeserializer is now unable to deserialize these records to a SpecificRecord. At first, because it could not find the class to deserialize to. I am instead now passing this class in my config:

```
      SchemaRegistryClient schemaRegistryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryUrl, 100);
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);
      config.put(SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true);
      config.put(AVRO_REFLECTION_ALLOW_NULL_CONFIG, true);
      config.put(AVRO_USE_LOGICAL_TYPE_CONVERTERS_CONFIG, true);

    if (isKey) {
      config.put(SPECIFIC_AVRO_KEY_TYPE_CONFIG, clazz.getName());
    } else {
      config.put(SPECIFIC_AVRO_VALUE_TYPE_CONFIG, clazz.getName());
    }
      deserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer(schemaRegistryClient, config, isKey);
```

However, when running:

```
  public T deserialize(byte[] array) throws IOException {
      Object bla = deserializer.deserialize(topic, array);
    return clazz.cast(bla);
  }
```

I now get
`java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record to COMPANY_NAMESPACE.record$`

There must be a way to handle producers setting whatever valid namespace and name they choose for their schemas, but I cannot figure out how to deserialize to a SpecificRecord in a case where they've chosen something like this.

For now, I am planning to fall back to using GenericRecord.

I am using confluent libraries with version 7.4.1.

I have stepped through the debugger but cannot find the moment at which the libs fall back to GenericRecord instead of the type I have told it to use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure the avro libs dont resort to GenericRecord as a fallback when deserializing to SpecificRecord doesn't work but rather throw an Exception that it couldn't find the class you are trying to deserialize to. So there must be something wrong with your clazz-class or your deserializer config.